# UX Research for more than one target group

Tags: user-research, research, target-users

I'm new to UI and UX Design and need some guide. I'm currently working on a project with a focus on two target groups. I want to know how to conclude on design goals, research questions, problem statement, empathy maps, personas, and so on. Do I create one of the mentioned above for each target group? or do I have to merge the questions, goals and so on for both target groups?

Comment: Not all of those dimensions are the same. In some cases, you'll need to do the research for each target, in some cases you won't need to do it. Furthermore, you'll need to compare both targets

Answer (score 0):

**Target group research variations**.
Target group differences can lead to massive variations of what you're looking to validate with your research.
A simple example could be novice vs expert users of a system. It might be hard to find commonalities between how you'd test for these two target groups using the same set of artifacts.

**Target grouping for research**.
If there isn't much of a differentiation between the target groups, such that your research goals and research questions are same for both groups, then you might wanna look at whether it makes sense to create those groups for the purpose of UX research.

Answer (score 0):

You might start with understanding why each group is a target. Why are they relevant and other groups are not? Why are they considered different from each other and not just one larger pool of users? What is everything that you need to know about the people in each group? (This can be converted to personas.)

Empathy maps for each group might be a good next step to understand them more, but you really need to dig into goals. Why would each group use your product or website? What are they not using instead? What is their main goal? What are other important goals to capture?

From there, research questions might start to percolate. What are the obstacles that are getting in the way of their goals? Or, let's say they're starting to use your product less - what are they using instead to achieve their goals? Why?

Once you understand your audiences and have your research questions, then you can come up with problem statements. These can be used for conversations with stakeholders, to find approaches to solutions.

This could work with one or multiple groups, but if you're researching multiple groups and they interface with each other (example: parents and children both using the same homework app but in different ways) you should note where they'll intersect and what observations and problems arise at those points.